# How to change PHP Server API to Apache 2.0 Handler from CGI/FastCGI?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, fastcgi, apache2-module

I have a Plesk 12 server in which PHP is running with Server API CGI/FastCGI. But some of my script requirements I have to change it to Apache 2.0 Handler.

I have performed several changes in Apache configs to enable Apache 2.0 Handler but not successful.

Please help me out of this.

Comment: Can you please provide more details?

Comment: @NoyGabay what kind of details you need? Please let me know i'll provide you

Comment: do you have access to parallels plesk admin panel? if not, then you need to contact your administrator to do it for you

Answer (score 2):

Edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
####    PHP as fast cgi
AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
Action php5-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php.fcgi
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

Restart the apache
 /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to parallels plesk admin panel, you can find the option under

`hosting services` (in the left panel) >> `service plan` (still in the left panel)

then you choose which service plan to change, then go to

`hosting parameters` tab (in the main panel)

then scroll down until you find the settings

**note:** this is valid for **plesk panel 11.5.30 Update #47** and if you have access to the **subscription plan** settings

Answer (score 0):

For php8.0 : a2disconf php8.0-fpm

Comment: could you explain why?